# Allowing linux firewall to receive packets for my code

Tags: c, linux, sockets, firewall

I wrote a c code for ping command and for some reason it doesn't receive any reply. I spent couple of days trying to find problem with the code, but later I have checked packet sending with wireshark. I found that the reply was send to me (the destination is unreachable, as it should be with destination IP I entered). In Internet I found that my firewall could cause this problem, but I didin't find any solution for it. So please help me, how can I add some kind of exeption for my firewall for the certain code? Thank you.

*EDITED*

The iptables output:

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination

Wireshark output:

> 17      0.641636029    192.168.0.134    192.168.0.1   ICMP    120 Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)

Also I probably made a mistake and the problem may be not in the receiving, but in sending packet

Comment: run `/etc/init.d/iptables stop` if it won't help - it's not a firewall

Comment: I cannot stop *iptables* for some reason, have tried as *service stop* too, also I'm using kali linux and I don't even have iptables in this location

Comment: then it is not a firewall

Comment: Do you have any ideas what it could possibly be?

Comment: Show some [MCVE] in  your question. Otherwise it is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check firewall using the following command `iptables -L -n`
 And provide output

Comment: Have edited my post just now

Comment: Unfortunatly it is not firewall

Comment: Oh, that is not so good for me, what it could possibly be and where should I search for a problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider using some library like [liboping](https://github.com/octo/liboping) or [libping](https://fossies.org/dox/libping-1.15/)

Be aware that `ping` uses [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) (see [icmp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html)). Your program is likely to require root privilege. So you need to run it as root, or use [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques.

Check systematically against failure *every* system call that you are using (see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for a list). Read [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and use [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) (or `strerror(errno)`).

Use also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your program to understand what system calls are done (and which one is failing).